# How do I best create a yearly resetting transaction number for a Java web application

Tags: java, database

I have a java web application using servlets & JSPs. It is a transaction based application.

Multiple systems connect to this web application and create multiple transactions in a day. I record every transaction in a database. I want to add a sequential number for every transaction. After the end of the financial year, the Transaction number should be reset to the initial number 1.

How should the number sequencing(generating) be processed? Should i create a utility table in DB, that persists the last Transaction number, based on which the very next transaction number is created?

Comment: Backticks are not for emphasis.  Stop that.  :P

Answer (score 2):

Use a DB sequence (most RDBMS's have them), and give your transaction table a unique key comprised of the transactionID and year.

You'll need some way of resetting the sequence at the start of each financial year.

Comment: For resetting yearly, this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942844/how-do-i-automatically-reset-a-sequences-value-to-0-every-year-in-oracle-10g